# Simplificación de código en python mediante un loop y transformar el resultado a cadena string

Tags: python, string, bucle-for, bucles

Si quiero definir una secuencia resultados de la forma `PIPPPINNNIPPPPPPPPPPINN`
para los siguientes elementos `planetas = 'AXDDCCCCSSDFQWEAACCCXXX'`, `porty = 'ASDF'` y `nick = 'ZXCV'`

Donde `P` y `N` son las iniciales del jugador que aventaja al otro e `I` es el posicionador cuando ambos jugadores están empatados.

El código con el que inicié la resolución es este:

```
porty = input('').upper()
nick = input('').upper()
planetas = input('').upper()
resultado=""
cont1=0
cont2=0
for resultado in planetas:
  for n in nick:
    if resultado == n:
      cont1 = cont1+1
for resultado in planetas:      
  for p in porty:
    if resultado ==p:
      cont2 = cont2+1

    if (cont1 > cont2):
      resultado +="P"
    else:
      if (cont1 > cont2):
        resultado +="N"
      else: 
        resultado +="I"
print(resultado)
```

Tengo problemas de identación e intuyo que debo establecer alguna forma de iteración para que me identifique todas las variables de la serie planetas, pero no entiendo cómo debo hacerlo. ¿Algunas sugerencias para recodificar mi código?

Comment: si vas a utilizar un patron recomiendo que utilices expresiones regulares

Comment: Gracias Christian

Comment: ¿Puede ocurrir que alguno de los jugadores tenga una letra repetida? ¿Puede ocurrir que una letra la tengan ambos jugadores?

Answer (score 0):

No termino de entender el juego.
Pero asumiré que un jugador no puede tener una letra que tengo el otro.
Asumo también que un jugador no puede tener letras repetidas.

Lo que haremos será iterar todas las letras de `planetas`.
Si la letra está en la lista de un jugador la añadiremos a su contador.
Para comprobar que una letra la tiene un jugador usaremos la palabra reservada `in` en vez de hacer la iteración que tú escribes y que da lugar a cometer errores.

Tras modificar los contadores comprobamos quién va ganando y añadiremos su inicial a una `string` llamada `resultado`.

```
resultado = ""
counter_porty = 0
counter_nick = 0
# Itero todos los elementos de planetas
for letra in planetas:
    # Compruebo qué jugador tiene la letra actual
    if letra in porty:
        counter_porty += 1
    elif letra in nick:
        counter_nick += 1

    # Añado al resultado quién va ganando
    if counter_porty > counter_nick:
        resultado += 'P'
    elif counter_porty == counter_nick:
        resultado += 'I'
    else:
        resultado += 'N'
print(resultado)
```